# Not Voting Helps the "Enemy"

Tags: probability

I have often heard people say "If candidate X is nominated, I'm not going to vote for anyone; I'm just going to stay home on Election Day."  A common response is "If you don't vote for X then you're helping Y get elected."  The logic seems to be you have to vote for someone you don't like, otherwise you are helping the other party.  I bring this up because of the recent election possibilities in the US. but also because I have heard this in past elections.  What does logic or math say about this kind of statement?

Please note that this is not a "political" question.  I am purely interested in what logic or mathematics says about this question.  Logically, is this statement valid?  Is there a line of reasoning that can help one decide such a statement?  In other words, an answer should take the form "Given a pool of voters and a choice of two candidates, if this person does this...."  This would help bring some rational thinking to the topic.

Comment: Is your question about comparing the two outcomes of "staying home" and "voting for $X$" and finding out in which of the two cases $Y$ is more likely to get elected? Or is it about the precise meaning of the expression "helping $Y$ get elected"?

Comment: Politics and your your civic duty are beyond the scope of this site.  But, from a personal point of view, I say you are not obligated to vote for anyone.

Comment: Math says very little about this topic--it's mostly a political science or sociology topic.  A single person has absolutely 0 influence on an election so it's not possible to state a single person's influence other than to say they have no influence (from a mathematical standpoint).  The bigger question you are asking is what if a _group_ of people decide not to vote (or not to vote for either party).  The answer, historically, is quite simple--the vote doesn't matter.  The way the electoral college is setup, these small minorities aren't heard and thus discouraged from voting in such a way.

Comment: Jared, your second sentence may be *pragmatically true* (not 'absolutely 0' influence, but sure, not much) *at the national level*, but at state elections in the US, it's not uncommon for elections to be determined by hundreds or *dozens* of voters. At local US elections, there are even semi-regular cases of tiebreakers happening. The rhetoric of "the individual's vote doesn't matter" misses these subtleties, to disastrous effects at these lower levels of US government. (Also it's simply false that small groups of people not voting for the major parties don't matter: see Nader in 2000)

Comment: @EricStucky I'm confused, you say I'm wrong but then you say that even state elections might be determined by "hundreds" or "dozens" of votes--these aren't single votes--and even if they were, you single vote doesn't matter.  I was making no point beyond the mathematical.  You are trying to make a political science/sociological point that I was not.  A single person voting for Nader didn't cause Gore to lose the election--it was a _large group_ of people voting for Nader that caused Gore to lose the election.

Comment: To be clear: I am indeed trying to make a political point that you were not: that a widespread acceptance of "the individual's vote doesn't matter", no matter how historically accurate, indirectly contributes to a democracy whose leaders do not represent their electorate.

Comment: @EricStucky Yes, I'm aware of the [Self-Fulfilling Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy).

Comment: I voted to close as "primarily opinion-based". You didn't state a clear mathematical question, and as a consequence the comments and answers have veered into the political. Depending on how you intended the question, it may have a mathmatical core that's suitable for this site. In that case you should focus the post on that mathematical question. If, on the other hand, the focus is on arguing which already known outcomes should or shouldn't be referred to as "helping $Y$ be elected", this is not the right site for that question.

Comment: @joriki I would like this to be a purely mathematical question but I lack the vocabulary to state it as such and I also worry that if I don't state it exactly it will get closed, so I am looking for some help on this. The question is not about politics or sociology.

Comment: @joriki  the question is not only for US elections but for any system of voting.  So, if someone tells me "You need to vote even if you don't like the candidates because you'll only help elect the enemy" I would like to be able to counter this with reason and facts based on logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say $a$ other people will vote for party/candidate $A$ and $b$ other people will vote for party/candidate $B$. Presumably their decision is independent of yours (unless this post motivates you to go and try to persuade them to change their mind :-).

If you stay home, candidate $A$ will receive a share $\frac a{a+b}$ of the votes and candidate $B$ will receive a share $\frac b{a+b}$.

If you vote for candidate $A$, candidate $A$ will receive a share $\frac{a+1}{a+b+1}$ of the vote and candidate $B$ will receive a share $\frac b{a+b+1}$.

If you vote for candidate $B$, candidate $A$ will receive a share $\frac a{a+b+1}$ of the vote and candidate $B$ will receive a share $\frac{b+1}{a+b+1}$.

Now lets compare these shares. We have

$$
\frac{a+1}{a+b+1}-\frac a{a+b}=\frac{(a+1)(a+b)-a(a+1+b)}{(a+b)(a+b+1)}=\frac b{(a+b)(a+b+1)}\gt0
$$

and

$$
\frac a{a+b+1}-\frac a{a+b}=\frac{a(a+b)-a(a+b+1)}{(a+b)(a+b+1)}=-\frac a{(a+b)(a+b+1)}\lt0\;.
$$

So candidate $A$ receives a greater share of the vote if you vote for here than if you stay at home, and she receives a lower share of the vote if you vote for $B$ than if you stay at home. Likewise (since the shares add to $1$), candidate $B$ receives a lower share of the vote if you vote for $A$ than if you stay at home, and he receives a greater share of the vote if you vote for $B$ than if you stay at home.

Thus you have three options, and we can strictly order them in the order of their effects on the vote shares. The vote share will be most favourable for $A$ if you vote for her, most favourable for $B$ if you vote for him, and in between if you stay home.

Thus, if your goal is to maximise the chances of one candidate winning and the other candidate losing (the two go hand in hand), you should vote for the candidate whom you want to win. Of course you may have other goals – to save the effort of going to vote, or to express protest at the available choices, or to destabilise the system, or to be cool and cynical. None of these can be captured in this calculation. But if the focus is on influencing the outcome of the election by your actions, and you have any preference at all for one candidate over the other, it makes no sense to stay home, since in that case the vote share of the preferred candidate will be lower than it would have been if you'd gone to vote, and that of the unpreferred candidate will be higher.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  So, if I understand you correctly, there is no basis to a claim that staying home (not voting) helps someone win.  So if I don't like A or B and would prefer neither win, me staying home will not do anything...its just one less vote.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Well, I think if you have no preference for either of them to win, then we can say much more generally, quite independent of any vote counting, that it doesn't make sense to go to vote -- even if it that did help one of the candidates win, you wouldn't care since you have no preference, no? My impression is that your question is more a linguistic and philosophical one than a mathematical one after all. It's a question about what constitutes "doing something". You have an option to make a difference, and if you choose not to exercise it, that also makes a difference.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: You can call that "doing something" or "staying at home", but you took a decision, and due to this decision the vote count will be in the middle between two other options that you could also have chosen. If you don't care about the result, then this is of course a good approach, but then why bother whether you're "helping the enemy", if that's just a tag and you don't actually have a preference against that "enemy"?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about this is if you are not voting and you only for the party x stands for then if you don't vote you are not helping X to reduce Y's lead.
In voting the the number of votes is always limited, so when you vote for X you are reducing Y's 1 vote and increases X's lead.In order to overcome one vote of Y,X needs two votes and vice versa

Comment: This isn't true. If you and I are running, and you have 2 votes already, I don't need 4 votes to beat you, just 3.

Comment: Yup That is right, what I meant is if you have 1 vote and I have 2.Then you need 2 votes to beat me.But the total votes is always a constant.
Lets take a case
Total Vote : 100
X:48
Y:49
Remaining:3
if one guy who is not voting since it is x and two others are voting equally
X:49
Y:50
So it helps Y

Comment: This is wrong because it's logically not symmetrical.  If by not voting you help reduce X's lead over Y, you conversely help reduce Y's lead over X.  It cannot, logically, be stated that you are helping one over the other since the same statement of "not helping" or "helping" can be made towards _both_ candidates.

Comment: @Jared  To have a symmetric situation, you must consider not two but three alternatives: vote for X, vote for Y, abstain.  Obviously, voting for X helps X and hurts Y, while voting for Y helps Y and hurts X.  But if Y is your least favourite, voting for Y is out of the question.  If you eliminate that possibility, you've broken the symmetry.    **Compared to the alternative of voting for X**, not voting helps Y and hurts X.

Answer (score 0):

A vote *not* for a person is *not* a vote for that person.  This statement is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

If we are to assume that one of two people will win, then a non-vote or a vote for a *third* person (not able to win) is the same.  However this is *not* the same as a vote for the person you dislike more--it's a non-vote--you do *not* contribute to the voting process.  You *only* contribute if you feel that you should have voted for one of the two candidates over the other.  In that sense you have subtracted a vote from the candidate you preferred--but it's *still not* an endorsement of the other candidate--and it's *still* less than an *actual* vote for that less desirable candidate.

In an *actual* election, it should be theoretically possible that we *do not* know who will win and thus any vote is a vote for that person and no other, regardless of likely outcomes.  Unfortunately, that's not the nature of voting.

Comment: Thank you for posting.  I edited my question.  See if this changes your answer.  I also commented above.